How to implement mui styled components in next js app router without using "use client"
I want to use mui styled components in nextjs 14 , but on each page i have to write "use client", i want to use nextjs ssr feature but it is forcing me for csr, how to implement it ? Please guide me.
I have searched for it but i always see it implemented in pages router, not in app router.

Did you try my suggestion on the answer below?

You can read the MUI documentation section about Next.js integration instructions, maybe you forgot some configuration. On MUI repo has some examples, this is the Material UI - Next.js App Router example, maybe it help you.
